# Is showing an ad after a home button press too annoying?

Tags: android, advertisement

I wanted for an Android app I'm developing to show an ad first time the user tries to exit the app, when done with the back button it works fine, but in the case the home button is the one that's pressed before showing the ad there's a 5 seconds delay until it's shown, and that with the home screen already being shown. Those 5 seconds are a security measure Android has implemented so an app cannot occupy the foreground of the phone for itself, so this cannot be helped in any way.

I think the user is likely to get annoyed by this, as a fact I know it would annoy me. Even if I tell the user that this is going to happen I think it would still annoy the user, although maybe to a lesser degree.

But I'm not really sure how much this would annoy my potential users, although it's sure to annoy some of them, maybe not enough not to include this.

Do you think it would be worth it to include this feature, as even if it annoys some users I could get more ad clicks, in comparison to not including it?

Comment: If would annoy you, why would you do it to someone who downloads your app? Unless the ad revenue will make you rich, I say skip it.

Comment: Pretty sure preventing the home button from going home, isn't possible on either Android or iOS. As it's one of the methods of exiting a crashed app.

Comment: Don't do it: An app I _very occasionally_ use behaves a bit like this with the BACK button: the app screen closes, the previous app or home screen becomes visible, and then an add appears – I don't know if this is deliberate or just bad implementation – but it is **truly** annoying. I only keep it because I use it so rarely – if I used it on anything like a regular basis, I'd ditch it for an alternative (and would never click the ad in either case).

Answer (score 3):

Showing an Ad when user is trying to exit your app? Off course it will annoy/frustrate the users, because they have already made a decision to leave your app and then you show them an Ad would be frustrating. No one would even look at the Ad when they have decided to leave the app. Additionally, it will work as a indirect message that says -

> You try to close me, and I will show you an Ad. Want to escape? Don't
>   open me again.

---

**Users don't mind going through Ads when they are engaged with their intent first**. You need to quietly push the Ads for them so they don't mind.

Comment: Showing a (dismissable) ad as you leave could just about be tolerated; having it pop-up a few seconds after the app has closed would not.

Comment: @TripeHound that will be a big surprise, right? And then, the OS will be blamed for that, because no app is open but there is an Ad.

Answer (score 1):

Ads are always annoying, especially when they intrude the screen after/while exiting or entering an app.

The main reason why this the one of the worst ways of showing ads is because the user sees an ad when he/she is expecting to see an app or the homescreen.

Few ways of keeping ads discrete and non-intrusive:

- **Embed them within the app layout** - Facebook does it really well. It shows ads like they are a post and shows the *Sponsored* badge to inform you that it's an ad
- **Place them at the bottom of the screen and adjust the app layout to incorporate them** - A lot of apps keep a fixed bottom area to place ads. That way it never comes in the way and is visible at the same time.

There are some practices that you can follow to make the ads less intrusive and annoying. I came across some answers that might help you.

- https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/47930/97993
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727426/4179589
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTnqcz6RJ-4